# How can i Split a pdf file related to each topic or headers in it by python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to split a pdf file in many section by every topic or header in this file.
Example : a research papers every one has an introduction section and background section and so on what i need is how can i extract each section alone in a file to separate them?

Comment: PDF files are very complicated and working with them is a hell. If you can get it as `Word` or other file then it should be easier.

Comment: @furas if i get it as word can i do what i want with it?

Comment: I think it could be simpler to do this. You can get paragraphs and check font size to recognize headers. In PDF you may have every char as separated object and you may have to check position `x,y` to see if it part of new section or not. But all depends on file and this is too broad problem. When you get error message then you can ask for help on Stackoverflow.